# Can you assign a range of numbers to a field in ms-access?

Tags: ms-access

I am making a simple database for some products, each of which is possible to have a thickness within a specified range of values, say, between 19.4 mm and 19.7 mm. I need to be able to make a search query for that field in such a way that if I search for a thickness of 19.65 mm, the items that have 19.65 within their range will be found.

This is my first time using Microsoft Access, and so I wanted to know if there is a simple method to achieve this, and if not, can you recommend any software I can use to achieve this?

Comment: This is really basic Access functionality. Have you studied an introductory tutorial book? A solid week with one will cover a lot. Edit question to show sample of data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming table has two fields for the thickness range:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE [enter some value] BETWEEN [Low] AND [High];`

Build a 'search form'. Select the search parameter from a combobox list or type it into a combobox or textbox. Then query can reference that control.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE Forms!formname.controlname BETWEEN [Low] AND [High];`